# SharePoint 2016 Search result doesn't retrieve aspx pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint 2016 site collection running with no problems without the search doesn't retrieve any aspx pages content in the search result.

Regards

Ashraf

Comment: Is the Search service configured? Did you start full or incremental crawl?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site settings -> Search Result Sources under Site Collection Administration -> Check whether you choose Local SharePoint results.

Comment: Yes, I checked it now and I saw that Local SharePoint results is already checked

Answer (score 0):

Edit Search Result page. Edit **Search Results** web part. Check in query bulider if you have `-FileType:aspx` in query.

`-FileType:aspx` will not return aspx page in results. If you have this in your query you need to remove it to see aspx pages in search results.

For more description see this link.
https://metashare.com/en/app/help/adminmanual/how-to-create-a-custom-search-results-page/#gsc.tab=0